# How to check if the SWT combo is currently opened?

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT combo box in my GUI. Is it possible to check if the combo box has been opened?
(I've a mechanism which refreshes the state shown in the combo box, when a user opens it sometimes it jumps between user selection and that what the algorithm thinks is fine, the user selection has a priority over everything else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combo SWT component have method `getListVisible()` which returns flag if combo dropdown list part is visible or not.. see [documentation for combo](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Combo.html) for details.

Comment: However the document is too long for seeking such a piece of info, so thank you for pointing out which method to look at!

Answer (score 0):

The response of Sorceror is about `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo`

If you need this method on `javax.swing.JComboBox` you can use `isPopupVisible()`