# Event notification if SWT Combo display list is visible

Tags: java, list, events, combobox, swt

I was checking for an event that indicates if the Combo display list is open, but did not see anything.

I thought of a mouse down/up event hook, but I quickly realized that a user presses and releases the mouse to display the list. Also, one can use a keyboard.

I saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579847/how-to-check-if-the-swt-combo-is-currently-opened), which said to use the `getListVisible()` method, however that would either some sort of timer. A mouse up event is not quite accurate for implementing the check and a timer seems like major overkill for a simple task.

```
cboServers = new Combo(this.cmptLogHtsControl, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);
cboServers.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
    }
});
gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
gridData.widthHint = 300;
cboServers.setLayoutData(gridData);
this.cboServers.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0)
    {
    }
});
```

Am I missing something? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the popup is done by the native control there probably isn't any way to see this.

Looking at the implementation of `Combo` on Mac OS X `getListVisible()` is done using events which are specific to OS X and are not exposed in the SWT API.

Comment: That means the answer given in question 14579847, mentioned in my question, was not a real answer, as it breaks WORA rules. That also means that I need to write my own dropdown. .Net is better, as that framework exposes these key events (show and hide the display list).

Comment: The `CCombo` control is written entirely using other SWT controls, you may be able to make a copy of that with the events you need. `getListVisible()` does run on all platforms, how it is implemented is very different on each platform.